# How do I create a dynamic inventory using Ansibles aws_ec2 plugin and group by KeyName?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have tried this:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-east-1
keyed_groups:
  - key: KeyName
    prefix: KeyName_
compose:
  - ansible_host: private_ip_address
```

Various combinations along this line using various cases of KeyName, key-name, key_name. but no dice.

I can't figure out how to debug it either, get a list of attributes to use that come with each host.

Answer (score 1):

One:

In all the combinations I tried I had not tried *key_name* as the key. Only the prefix. This sorted it it out.

Two:

Debugging host variables can be done by running.

`ansible localhost -m debug -a 'var={{ hostvars | to_nice_json }}'`

I would strongly recommend you pipe that in to a file as my out put was almost twenty thousand lines out output.